# Why do i have set my canvas width to window innerWidth in JS and canvas width 100% in css?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I don't get why I can't set the width and height to 100% in CSS ***OR*** set width and height to inner window width and height but, I have to do both. If I don't set both of them my canvas element won't show my drawing. Same thing with height too. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>TESTING CANVAS DRAWING</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
      }

      canvas {
        border: 2px soild black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas>
      Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    <script>
      //startup code
      let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight

      //drawing

      let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.fillRect(659, 327, 100, 100); // pixel coordinates start from the the top right
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're drawing the rectangle outside of the canvas in both cases (starting from the right edge of the canvas, and then drawing 100 pixels to the right). Don't set CSS dimensions for a canvas, it makes the drawing blurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS and javascript, in this case, are referring to two separate sizes. The Canvas element has it's own specific dimensions (default 300x150 i think) as well as the HTMLElement dimensions that can be controlled with CSS.
You can just set the dimensions in css and use relative values, eg:

```js
      //startup code
      let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      //canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      //canvas.height = window.innerHeight

      //drawing
      let x = 659 * canvas.width/ document.body.offsetWidth;
      let width = 100 * canvas.width / document.body.offsetWidth;
      let y = 327 * canvas.height / document.body.offsetHeight;
      let height = 100 * canvas.height / document.body.offsetHeight;
      let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.fillRect(x, y, width, height); // pixel coordinates start from the the top right
```

I'm not setting the values but it should look the same if a little blurrier.
Think of it as a monitor; the CSS controls the physical size of the monitor and JS canvas dimensions are the resolution.

Comment: I tried this and i still need to set the width & height in CSS PS. Sorry for late replay

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tested the latest FF, Chrome and Edge and couldn't get the black rectangle not to display.

Comment: I’m using Microsoft Edge